# Overriding a method where parameter type references own class

Tags: java

I have the following java code:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {

    public TreeNode<T> getParent() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setParent(TreeNode<T> parent) {

    }

    public List<TreeNode<T>> getChildren() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<TreeNode<T>> children) {

    }

    public T getData() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {

    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a class that extends the one above, like the following:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> extends TreeNode<T> {
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeftChild() {
        return null;
    }
    public void setLeftChild() {
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRightChild() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setRightChild() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setChildren(List<BinaryTreeNode<T>> children) {

    }

}
```

However, the last method won't compile because the parameter `children` is not of type `List<TreeNode<T>>`. I understand why this happens (because `List<BinaryTreeNode<T>>` is not considered a subtype of `List<TreeNode<T>>`), but what is the best way to fix something like this?

I know that I can just define the `children` parameter to be of type `List<TreeNode<T>>`, but if possible I would like to enforce it to be of type `List<BinaryTreeNode<T>>`.

Comment: try List<? extends BinaryTreeNode>

Comment: Add a generic parameter identifying the current type, e.g., `class TreeNode<T, N extends TreeNode<T, N>>`. And make the method `setChildren(List<N> children)`.

Comment: If the only children of BinaryTreeNode are BinaryTreeNodes, *what type are the leaves*?

Comment: @AndyThomas BinaryTreeNodes, but without any children of their own.

Comment: @shmosel I had the same idea, but you need to change the children type of the children. As you wrote it, the children have children of the same type. In fact, it should be `class TreeNode<T, N extends TreeNode<T, ?>>`, as the grandfather might not know the type of the grandchildren.

Comment: @shmosel @MalteHartwig Can you show the rest of the code as well? because now I am confused about how the rest of the function declarations in the original `TreeNode` class should look

Comment: @MalteHartwig *As you wrote it, the children have children of the same type.* I don't see any indication otherwise. Did I miss some requirement?

Comment: @shmosel **Correction** op actually said that the tree has nodes of one and the same type only ("references own class"). Sorry. I thought of the case where normal treeNodes have BinaryTNs as children that have children of yet another type. That wouldn't be possible with your typing.

Comment: @SimonZhu Just replace every `TreeNode<T>` with `N`. And the subclass should extend `TreeNode<T, BinaryTreeNode<T>>`.

Comment: @MalteHartwig - I misunderstood the name to suggest only that the node was binary, rather than that the entire tree was binary. Second question - if a TreeNode supports setChildren() with an arbitrary number of children, and BinaryTreeNode does not -- can a BinaryTreeNode be used wherever a TreeNode can be? Is it really a TreeNode? Or should TreeNode.setChildren() be moved into a different interface, that more limited implementations don't implement?

Comment: @AndyThomas I guess that yould be done by parameter checking and IllegalArgumentExceptions. Take Unmodifiable Lists as IdentityHashMap as examples where sub classes (even in the JDK) "violate" contracts.

Comment: @shmosel I summed up what we talked about and ran into an issue with the recursive generic types. Could you have a look at my answer? I am afraid it won't work out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not coming from the lists not being subclasses, it's because you can't override a method and upcast its parameter.

if you have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public void f(A a) {}
}

public class B extends A
{
    public void problem(){}
    public void f(B a) 
    {
        a.problem();
    }
}
```

Since B extends from A, you could have the following code running:

```
A a1 = new B();
A a2 = new A();
a1.f(a2);
```

when that code will run, it will try to execute the function "problem" on an A instance that doesn't have it.
That's why in general you can't override the parameters with classes that inherit the original type.

Now, you can leave the parameter as List> children, but then you might get nodes that aren't binary, which I assume you don't want.

If you're sure that's the way you want the inheritance to be, you can check the type of "children" at the beginning of the method and throw an exception if it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what shmosel proposed:

```
public class TreeNode<T, N extends TreeNode<T, N>> {
    public N getParent() { return null; }

    public void setParent(N parent) {}

    public List<N> getChildren() { return null; }

    public void setChildren(List<N> children) {}

    public T getData() { return null; }

    public void setData(T data) {}
}
```

The downside is that your Nodes now have to by typed with a "redundant" generic type. That is because you try to counter the fact that sub classes can act as object of super classes.

Your Binary Node class would look like this:

```
class BinaryTreeNode<T> extends TreeNode<T, BinaryTreeNode<T>>
```

---

As an alternative and for further reading, try this article:

https://www.sitepoint.com/self-types-with-javas-generics/

Comment: You don't need to expose the second parameter in the subclass. See my comment above.

Comment: Thanks, took a while to click.

Comment: The parent type should probably be `N` too.

Comment: I think it will still be possible to game this construct to mix the nodes up, though.

Comment: Yes, that's the unavoidable reality of generics in Java.